# Axios + Electron.js Error: `xhr.js:120 Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent"`

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, electron, axios

My electron app uses `axios` to communicate with REST API endpoints, causing the following error to be thrown:

> xhr.js:120 Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent"

This results in the JS console to be flooded with such error messages. Is there a known fix for this issue?

*Using node 12.6.0, electron 6.0.1, axios 0.19.0 on Mac OS X Mojave*

Comment: Are you solve the problem?

Comment: @FroDK Not yet...